# Sealant/adhesive to reattach ceramic hob trim

Tags: kitchens, adhesive, sealant

The adhesive sealant attaching the glass of my Electrolux ceramic hob to its metal trim/edging is no longer adhesive/sealant and needs to be replaced (see image).

I don't know what the original sealant is, but it is black and seems less rubbery than silicone: it holds a fingernail impression. Two questions:

1. Assuming I need something resistant to (moderate) heat, spilled boiling water/hot oil, hob cleaning chemicals, etc. what adhesive/sealants are recommended/appropriate? Note that the adhesive does not (now) need to be especially strong (originally the hob hung from the trim, but it is now supported) and should be replaceable/removable (i.e. no destructive chemical bonding to either the metal or the glass).
2. Tips or tricks for removing the existing sealant along the other two edges (so that everything can be thoroughly cleaned.

Please note that I am in the UK and would strongly prefer recommendations that can be satisfied from domestic suppliers.

**UPDATE 1**

Electrolux were contacted and replied that the trim would have been factory fitted and they could only recommend (what I would expect to be an expensive) "repair". A DIY alternative is therefore required.

**UPDATE 2**

In fairness to Electrolux it should be noted that one can see at the corner metal brackets that *would* support the hob, *if* the cut-out were correctly sized. The cut-out was however both too big and uneven and none of the brackets engaged significantly with the worktop, thus *leaving* the hob to hang.

I would say that the lip of the brackets could perhaps be wider, but had it been well fitted the current problems might not have occurred even with the existing narrow bracket lips.

[image: Electrolux Ceramic Hob with detached trim]

Comment: Would contact  Electrolux, they will know the exact adhesive you need to use.  Might be something you can pick up in a store, or might need a special type.

Comment: @crip659 I have called them (voicemail left, agents are "extra busy"... as always), sent message and reviewed the website advice/knowledge base. I am waiting the usual indefinite period for response(s). I appreciate the independent, always accessible and usually timely advice I get on Stack Exchange :)

Comment: Seeing you only need a sealant, instead of a glue/adhesive to hold a hot surface/pieces/pots in place/up, a hi temp silicone should work.  Would be careful using hob cleaners near it.  The glass surface might clean with a window/glass paint scraper(razor blade type).

Comment: Electrolux has to recommend their repair, even if expensive, since the trim was made to hold up the hob.  If you or someone else went back to using that trim to hold the hob and were heating a big pot of oil, bad stuff would happen plus lawsuits.

Comment: @crip659, surely the trim in the photo isn't providing mechanical support of the whole cooktop?

Comment: @spuck   #1 in the question, OP said the hob hung from the trim.  Do not know how or why, but is enough to be careful with suggestions.  Just need to watch youtube vids of turkey fryers.

Comment: @spuck yes, it hung. I was surprised too. Some side springs provided a little vertical friction but they were mostly to keep it from moving horizontally. Hob not hugely heavy... but it is now supported by brackets!

Comment: Honestly, ask Electrolux for a quote for a repair. While it might be prohibitively expensive, it might turn out to be much less than you're expecting and you might determine that it's worthwhile to spend a bit more for the knowledge that it's not bodged together, but is a proper fix.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I used black OB1 sealant for its waterproofness, chemical and moderate temperature resistance.

The repair was completed by slicing the trim from the hob where it was still attached on the other two sides by sliding a very sharp blade between the trim and the hob surface. This cut through the remaining sealant, and the excess on both sides and trim/hob was then scraped off.

The trim and hob were scrubbed and degreased before a narrow (3mm) bead of sealant was applied to the underside of the inner edge of the trim 1-2 mm behind a tiny "retaining" lip, which, if in contact with the job glass would ensure 1mm space remained so the joint would not be starved.

Refitting was performed by creating a right-angle alignment jig on the kitchen surface on two sides of the cut-out so that the correct overlap was predetermined all round and the trim merely had to be located with respect to the jig edges and then "hinged" down into place.

There being only a small gap between trim and hob, the 3mm bead was quite sufficient - a little squeezed out on each side when the trim was pressed back into place. The excess will be removed later with White Spirits as recommended for OB1.

I note that the OB1 flowed steadily under only moderate pressure and was easy to control.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to update with your solution. It would be fantastic if you were to come back in a year to let us know how this is holding up.

Comment: @FreeMan will try to remember :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a high temperature RTV sealant. Ideally, a black one to match the color of your cooktop.